# Headless Selenium/Protractor not sending output to Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e, linemanjs

I am using:

Firefox 30
selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar
Xvfb
Ubuntu Headless
Lineman grunt spec-e2e

I am able to run Xvfb, Firefox, and lineman grunt spec-e2e with no errors.

On all terminals I run `export DISPLAY=:10`

I run `Xvfb :10 -ac` in one terminal with no issues, I see:

```
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension GLX
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic, removing from list!
```

On a separate terminal, I run Firefox:

```
one@node ~/github/load-balancer-service/app/js/loadbalancer/controllers $ firefox

(process:16020): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":10".
```

Finally, in lineman I run (with a additional session of `lineman run` also):

```
one@node ~/github/load-balancer-service $ lineman grunt spec-e2e
Running "spec-e2e" task
Starting selenium standalone server...
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.14.13.161:42182/wd/hub
one@node ~/github/load-balancer-service $
```

But the issue I am having is there is no output going to the terminal window that is running firefox. When I run the spec-e2e, I do see the Xvfb terminal window have this output:

```
6 XSELINUXs still allocated at reset
SCREEN: 0 objects of 256 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DEVICE: 0 objects of 96 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CLIENT: 0 objects of 136 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
WINDOW: 0 objects of 32 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
PIXMAP: 1 objects of 16 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 4 objects of 16 bytes = 64 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 1 objects of 8 bytes = 8 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 6 objects, 88 bytes, 0 allocs
1 PIXMAPs still allocated at reset
PIXMAP: 1 objects of 16 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 4 objects of 16 bytes = 64 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 1 objects of 8 bytes = 8 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 6 objects, 88 bytes, 0 allocs
4 GCs still allocated at reset
GC: 4 objects of 16 bytes = 64 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 1 objects of 8 bytes = 8 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 5 objects, 72 bytes, 0 allocs
1 CURSORs still allocated at reset
CURSOR: 1 objects of 8 bytes = 8 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 1 objects, 8 bytes, 0 allocs
1 CURSOR_BITSs still allocated at reset
TOTAL: 0 objects, 0 bytes, 0 allocs
```

But I do not see the output of the spec-e2e going to the firefox window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must use `selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar` and not other versions.